# Bootstrap PHP unknown row in page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I started doing my school project and learning bootstrap basics but i have one problem with php code. I dont know how to delete this row in code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z66u4.jpg (or see below)

[image]

That red box.
As you can see in properties there is " ". When i delete it, row disappear. My index.php :
http://pastebin.com/K9GEF5mb (or see below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ryby.sk</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
                <div id="kontajner">
                        <?php
                                include("header.php");
                        ?>
                        <div id="body">
                                <div class= "container" >
                                        <div class="jumbotron" id="na_stred">
                                                <h1>Vitajte na stránke www.ryby.sk</h1>
                                                <p>Stránka je hlavne zameraná na informácie o sladkovodných rýbach.</p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class= "container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                                        <div class="page-header">
                                                                                <h2> Akvaristika </h2>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                                <p> gvfdgsdfghsf ghhfg hd gdgsdfghsf ghhfg hd gdgsdfghsf ghhfg hd gdgsdfghsf ghhfg hd gdgsdfghsf ghhfg hd gdgsdfghsf ghhfg hd g</p>
                                                                                <p> Zdroj: lblablalb </p>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div> 
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="footer">
                                <div class="navbar-inverse navbar-default navbar-bottom footer">
                                                        <div class="container">
                                                                <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Bezo production</p>
                                                                <a href="#contact" class=" navbar-btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" role="button" >Napíšte nám</a>
                                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Everything is OK, but when I add include("header.php"); than this row appears. Can you help me please? I am solving this problem for one week :(

Comment: Show us the code in `header.php`, it's quite likely that the issue stems from that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/niAaL2fg here is the header.php, thanks

Comment: This is the white-space that you're seeing: http://minus.com/i/RjgGKCJlEsqo

Comment: i deleted all white-space from index.php but still " " there and white row

Comment: I'd rather work with output buffers in this case, instead of putting `include` in middle of source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sources for the whitespace in your code. I have indicated them with XXX, and the one newline is indicated by Y in `index.php`.

In `index.php`:

```
                <div id="kontajner">
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<?php
                                include("header.php");
                        ?>Y
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<div id="body">
```

And in `header.php`:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
```

You should keep in mind though, that whitespace does not matter in HTML.

**UPDATE:**

As @hanzo2001 points out, it's possible to include code as follows:

```
<div><?php echo "Hello!"; ?></div>
```

Or to demonstrate the principle more extremely:

```
<div><?php 

if (1==1) 
{
    echo "Hello!"; 
}

?></div>
```

Both of which will render as:

```
<div>Hello!</div>
```

Comment: I completly changed white space here and it dont works for me. Now i have three white rows: http://i.imgur.com/jtig0EG.jpg index.php http://pastebin.com/cr0VkHZy header.php http://pastebin.com/Q4bNySdj uvod.html http://pastebin.com/XgSyBiR1 footer.html http://pastebin.com/9Jnpv50c

Comment: You have to remove the whitespace from *each of the files you include*.

Comment: You should add that you can actually write it in a single line as such: `<div><?php /*code*/ ?>`